# Enter on text field not working in webpages

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to automate a process on webpages. The element is

```
<input 
    aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-owns="search-dropdown-results" 
    data-accessibility-id="header-search-input-field" 
    data-anchor-id="HeaderSearchInputField" 
    data-lpignore="true" 
    type="text" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    placeholder="Search stores, dishes, products"
    inputmode="search" 
    id="FieldWrapper-0" 
    aria-describedby="search-dropdown-results" 
    class="Input__InputContent-sc-1o75rg4-3 idveBz" v
    alue=""
>
```

First, I entered a text in the field and then I want to press Enter. But the Enter part is not working. Please help.

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('FieldWrapper-0');
inputElement.value = "TEXT";
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'key': 'Enter' }));
```

Comment: What do you imagine to happen on `Enter` key? 

Comment: An event is a __result__ of an user (or environment) action, you can emulate events, but you can't trigger user actions with JS on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you completely messed up the code. Here is the JS version.

Try and let me know if it works.

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById('FieldWrapper-0'); 
inputElement.value = "TEXT"; 
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'key': 'Enter' })
inputElement.dispatchEvent(event, { bubbles: true }); 



inputElement.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
        alert('Keyboard Clicked');
 });
```

```html
I am trying to automate a process on webpages. The element is

<input aria-expanded="false" 
       aria-owns="search-dropdown-results" 
       data-accessibility-id="header-search-input-field" 
       data-anchor-id="HeaderSearchInputField" 
       data-lpignore="true" type="text" 
       autocomplete="off" 
       placeholder="Search stores, dishes, products" 
       inputmode="search" id="FieldWrapper-0" 
       aria-describedby="search-dropdown-results" 
       class="Input__InputContent-sc-1o75rg4-3 idveBz" 
       value="">
```

Comment: CLick on input field and press enter